# Getting props from children — default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*EDIT: CodePen link [here](https://codepen.io/Eugleo/live/jOVbBpd).*

I'm (ab)using JSX to make a form-building 'DSL' for some of my non-technical colleagues. There's a `SingleChoice` component that can be used like this:

```
<SingleChoice>
  <Option value="A">
    // ... what to show when A is chosen
  </Option>
  <Option value="B">
    // ... what to show when B is chosen
  </Option>
</SingleChoice>
```

The result is a `<div>` full of radio button inputs, and under the block of inputs, there are the conditional elements (based on what option is chosen).

In other words, the `Option` elements don't render anything by themselves, they are there just to signal to the parent how many radio buttons there are, what are their labels and what should be shown when X is chosen. They are literally empty shells, made just to carry their props, like this:

```
function Option({label, value, children}) { return <></> }
```

Yes, I could instead pass those as an array of objects `{ value: string, show: ReactNode }`, but that's not a friendly syntax for my non-dev colleagues.

Now, to the question. In the parent I go through all his children and render the input based on their value:

```
...
{children.map(ch => <> <input ... /> {ch.props.value} </>)}
...
```

The problem is, this only works when I manually pass a `value` prop to the `Option` component. E.g. when I have

```
function Yes({..., value = "Yes"}) { ... }
```

and I do

```
<SingleChoice>
  <Yes />
</SingleChoice>
```

the label is empty, as if it didn't see the default prop value. Why is that happening? Is it a bug? And how do I implement this properly? Remember, I don't really want to expose any of the implementation details to the user who writes the form (so no explicit callback passing).

The only "proper" way I could think of would be creating a context with a callback in the parent, which all the children would look up and call with their values. The problem is, there would be *a lot* of contexts made and updated this way, and I fear the performance implications.

Comment: Can you share code in a fiddle or stackblitz link?

Comment: @Mahdizoraghi Done: [here's the link](https://codepen.io/Eugleo/live/jOVbBpd).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what you want to have happen. As far as I can tell from your code on Codepen, a default prop value is never defined so when you call

```
<Yes/>
```

without passing it a prop it doesn't get rendered by your parent component. Also, a react function should just accept props as a parameter, you don't need to define value and children.

Comment: You're right, I totally forgot the imporant part in the codepen (i.e. setting the default value in `Yes`). Please see the updated version now.

Comment: I found some problems I'll add them in another answer bc comments have limited functionality

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering in another answer to get the formatting

- The first error you have is you run ReactDOM.render in the beginning of your code. You should add it at the end of the code, or else default values won't be used(I don't know why this is).
- The second is that your functions aren't really react. In react functions take one parameter, props. You can reference value or children as props.value or props.children.

not react: `function Yes({value = "Yes1", children}) { return <span></span> }`

react: `function Yes(props){ return <span>?+{props.value}</span> }`

- The third is that declaring defaultProps is done through the defaultProps command in react. So instead of setting a parameter to a value(because again, no parameters) you should write:

`Yes.defaultProps={ value:"Yes1" }`

- Finally, your function singleChoice isn't really react as well. Theres definitely a cleaner way to refactor your code then scrolling through the yes components and checking their value. However, you can do what you want. If you fix the other problems it should work as you intended.

Comment: Ok, the first and the last I will try, but isn't `function Yes({value = "Yes1", children})` just a function with one argument, which is just unpacked right at the definition site? i.e. "really react", as you would say?

Comment: Ok, now, when I use `defaultProps` it _does_ indeed work, but I've read [elsewhere](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1133878326358171650) that default props are deprecated and will be removed later — and that default parameters (like I used here) is the way to go.

Comment: stateless react functions should only take props as an argument. Taken straight from the official react docs - 'This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element.' I don't know why you're choosing to use react for this project when you're ignoring reacts features. Also that twitter post is just a proposition to get rid of default props.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, my function _does_ take a single props argument. See [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-function-arguments) for details.